# Can't call IFileSystemOperations.Open() method in powershell script

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, azure

I am passing a DataLakeStoreFileSystemManagementClient instance, named `_adlsFileSystemClient`, to a powershell script, and from there I wish to do the following.

```
_adlsFileSystemClient.FileSystem.Open(_adlsAccountName, filePath))
```

The following is my Powershell Script

```
param([System.Object]$dlsFSMC)
Add-Type -Path C:\Users\..\source\repos\tester\packages\Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Store.2.4.0-preview\lib\net452\Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Store.dll"
$strm = $dlsFSMC.FileSystem.Open(<name>,<path>)
```

Where name and path I have actual string values in those places.
I get an error message as follows.

> Method invocation failed because
>   [Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Store.FileSystemOperations] does
>   not contain a method named 'Open'.

I am confused why I'm getting the above error when `_adlsFileSystemClient.FileSystem.Open(_adlsAccountName, filePath))` works perfectly fine in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Open` is a [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.datalake.store.filesystemoperationsextensions.open?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Management_DataLake_Store_FileSystemOperationsExtensions_Open_Microsoft_Azure_Management_DataLake_Store_IFileSystemOperations_System_String_System_String_System_Nullable_System_Int64__System_Nullable_System_Int64__System_Nullable_System_Guid__), to call it you would need to call the static function and pass in the object.

```
param([System.Object]$dlsFSMC)
Add-Type -Path C:\Users\..\source\repos\tester\packages\Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Store.2.4.0-preview\lib\net452\Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Store.dll"
$strm = [Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Store.FileSystemOperationsExtensions]::Open($dlsFSMC.FileSystem, <name>,<path>)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Scott. I've been racking my brain for a couple hours over this one.